# Inverse Fourier Transform of a sum of 2 off-set triangle

Tags: fourier-transform

I'd like to get some help finding the original function of:

$$f(w) = T(w-1) + T(w+1)$$  to find $f(x)$.

I tried to apply on both T functions the inverse integral, while swapping $w$ with $-x$ but i get $-f(x)$.

i'd like to apologize if the syntax is wrong.. hope you'd understand.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What does "$\mid f(x)$" mean?